# Building the binary distribution of oozie fails

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I was searching for the binary distribution of oozie here:

http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/oozie/3.3.2/

It has only the source distribution. Is binary distribution not available?

So, I tried to build from this source using

```
./bin/mkdistro.sh
```

It went fine but stopped at a point:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Oozie Core 3.3.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from/to local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk): No connector available to access repository local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk) of type legacy using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ oozie-core ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ oozie-core ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ oozie-core ---
[INFO] Compiling 385 source files to /usr/local/oozie/oozie/core/target/classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (default) @ oozie-core ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:build-classpath (create-mrapp-generated-classpath) @ oozie-core ---
[INFO] Wrote classpath file '/usr/local/oozie/oozie/core/target/test-classes/mrapp-generated-classpath'.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ oozie-core ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 79 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ oozie-core ---
[INFO] Compiling 245 source files to /usr/local/oozie/oozie/core/target/test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) @ oozie-core ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /usr/local/oozie/oozie/core/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Concurrency config is parallel='classes', perCoreThreadCount=false, threadCount=1, useUnlimitedThreads=false
./bin/mkdistro.sh: line 71:  6907 Killed                  mvn clean package assembly:single ${MVN_OPTS} "$@"

ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
```

Can someone point me to the binary distribution or help me in resolving this build issue?

I have maven version 3.

Also tried with the following option, but didnt help.

```
$ export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using OpenJDK that was causing this issue.

Switched to Sun/Oracle JDK 6 and the build went fine.